Local broadcast cannot be found in mempool
After sending a raw transaction (SendRawTransaction (raw_tx, 100000)) and after local broadcasting, the transaction does not show up on platforms such as mempool.space. What might be the reason?

What does your debug.log say after you submit the transaction? Is it perhaps a conflict?

There is no error message, but the txid cannot be found in the debug.rog. However, the client. sendRawTransaction returned the txid. Is it possible that my transaction was not broadcasted? How can I make mempool or other mining pools receive my transaction

Is your transaction non-standard? Anything special about it?

This is a full RBF transaction with a rate exceeding 10000. Is there any platform that supports transactions with a rate exceeding 10000? Mempool.space will prompt "code": -25, "message": "Fee excesses maximum configured by user (e.g. - maxtxfee, maxfee)"

Assuming you mean 10,000 sat/vB, you may be overpaying by a factor of 3,000× currently. That’s why the 1,000 sat/vB warning is implemented in some wallet software. Are you reprioritizing a parent transaction so that you actually want to pay that much?

The second argument in the sendrawtransaction RPC is maxfeerate specified expressed in the unit [BTC/kvB].
100,000 BTC/kvB = 100 BTC/vB = 10,000,000,000 sat/vB

The value of 100,000 BTC/kvB that you provided is vastly in excess of sane feerates, so it looks like your node may have not broadcast the transaction to prevent overspending. As the documentation states, if you are willing to accept any feerate, you can set the second parameter to 0. I would however encourage you to carefully validate that your transaction is sending the remaining amount from the inputs to change outputs, which is a commonly overlooked issue with using raw transactions, as the combination of accepting any feerate and forgetting to specify a change output may lead to the majority of your funds being dropped to the transaction fees.
